# ACF Post Object returns false

Tags: php, html, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am trying to display a single post object in a page but it's as if there is nothing selected. I have tried var_dump on it and it returns false

```
<?php $post_object = get_field('resource');
    var_dump($post_object);
    if ($post_object):
        $post = $post_object;
        setup_postdata( $post );  ?>
        <div><?php the_title(); ?></div>
        <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I have done exactly as the documentation says, any thoughts[image]

Comment: Which documentation?

Comment: ACF https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/post-object/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry about that, I had done a wp query and post loop before this and it was causing some sort of conflict. After the loop I had to do `wp_reset_postdata()`